# How to align element at the bottom of screen using CSS?

Tags: html, css, position

How do I align an element at the bottom of a window (independent of the screen size), BUT it remains in that position such that when the window height is reduced (when a user alters window size) it remains in that exact location and is out of view in the window ?

I feel this may require more than just CSS. If so can anyone guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: calc(100vw / 2 - 200px); width: 400px; text-align: center; background-color: #ff0000;">Bottom center text<br />Hello center div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I've just plugged in your code but when the window height is reduced the div element still remains at the bottom of the window as opposed to going out of view .. is there any way to amend this ?

Comment: Add some javascript, get current viewport height onload, add event handler on viewport change, update the div element with bottom: -(oHeight - cHeight ) * -1px; Don't think it can be done with css

Comment: While your code may answer the PO's question, you should add a brief explanation of what you have done and how that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  .box {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: -9px -10px 10px -10px black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10vh;
    right: 10vw;
  }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I've just plugged in your code but when the window height is reduced the div element still remains at the bottom of the window as opposed to going out of view .. is there any way to amend this ?

Comment: With jsfiddle it's happening. Have you tried it with html file?